# Converting datetime timezone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this date `"2021-06-13T08:10:27.00013004+08:00"` in the `Asia/Singapore` timezone.

I want to convert it into Etc/UTC timezone and I am doing this approach.

```
var year = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, year: 'numeric'});
var month = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, month: '2-digit'});
var day = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, day: '2-digit'});
var hour = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, hour: '2-digit'});
var minute = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, minute: '2-digit'});
var second = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, second: '2-digit'});
```

I know this is not really efficient but working to some extent, I am doing it in Google Apps script.

but the issue is for the above date, my conversion is giving me.

```
2021/06/13/24 10_27_000
```

this date. which is not even possible? It should results into

```
2021/06/13/23 10_27_000
```

in 23 hours instead of 24. Can you please help me with this?

I want to convert Asia/Singapore timezone to Etc/UTC, for more details. I have this filename `ShawTower__2021-06-13-08-10-27_00013004.jpg` from which I am extracting the data as

```
var timestamp = filename.match(/\d+/g).map(String);
var actualDate = "" + timestamp[0] + "-" + timestamp[1] + "-" + timestamp[2] + "T" + timestamp[3] + ":" + timestamp[4] + ":" + timestamp[5] + "." + timestamp[6] + "+08:00";
```

is it possible in plain JS so

1. Attach a timezone to DateTime (not convert at first)
2. Convert it to another timezone

any help would be wonderful thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript `Date` objects are always in the [UTC timezone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). To display a date in a particular timezone using Apps Script, use this pattern:

```
function testUtcDateString() {
  const filename = 'ShawTower__2021-06-13-08-10-27_00013004.jpg';
  console.log(getUtcDateString_(filename));
}

function getUtcDateString_(filename) {
  const fromTimezone = '+08:00';
  const toTimezone = 'UTC';
  const dateString = filename.replace(/^.*(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/, '$1T$2:$3:$4') + fromTimezone;
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateString), toTimezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
}
```

Note that you may need to use a different value for the `+08:00` bit, depending on the timezone of your *script project*. You can get the script timezone with [Session.getScriptTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone()).

To get the result string in another format, use a different `format` pattern. See [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format).

Answer (score 0):

MomentJs is a great library for formatting and super simple to use: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Example

```
const formattedDateTime = moment(dateTime, currentFormat).format(newFormat);
```

See their documentation for the correct formatting strings

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `00` or `24` hours is not even possible for your date? It looks like JS, GAS and Python assume that there should be `00` or `24`.

JS:

```js
var actualDate = "2021-06-13T08:10:27.00013004+08:00";

var year   = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, year:   'numeric'});
var month  = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, month:  '2-digit'});
var day    = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, day:    '2-digit'});
var hour   = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, hour:   '2-digit'});
var minute = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, minute: '2-digit'});
var second = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, second: '2-digit'});

var str = [year, month, day, hour].join("/") + " " + [minute, second, "000"].join("_");

console.log(str); // output: 2021/06/13/00 10_27_000
```

GAS:

```
function myFunction() {

  var actualDate = "2021-06-13T08:10:27.00013004+08:00";

  var year   = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, year:   'numeric'});
  var month  = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, month:  '2-digit'});
  var day    = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, day:    '2-digit'});
  var hour   = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, hour:   '2-digit'});
  var minute = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, minute: '2-digit'});
  var second = new Date(actualDate).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Etc/UTC", hour12: false, second: '2-digit'});

  var str = year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/" + hour + " " + minute + "_" + second + "_000"

  Logger.log(str); // output: 2021/06/13/24 10_27_000

}
```

Python:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

date = datetime.fromisoformat('2021-06-13T08:10:27+08:00')
local_date = date.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Etc/UTC'))
print(local_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H %M_%S_000')) # output: 2021/06/13/00 10_27_000
```

**Update**

Based on @doubleunary answer, another GAS implementation, which gives the same `24` hours:

```
function main() {
  const date = new Date('2021-06-13T08:10:27.00013004+08:00');
  const timezone = 'UTC';
  const dateString = Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'yyyy/MM/dd/kk mm_ss_000');

  Logger.log(dateString); // output: 2021/06/13/24 10_27_000
}
```